# Definite integral approximated by Riemann sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f$ be defined on [0,1] and is in $L^2(0,1)$. I would like to study the difference between $(\int_0^1f(x)dx)^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)^2$. I have tried that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)^2&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)^2-2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}f(x)dx\right)\\
&=\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2-2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}f(x)dx\right).
\end{align*}

I expected to obtain that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)^2=\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2+\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})\;\mbox{as}\;n\to\infty\;\;(1).
\end{equation}

Could you do me a favor? Or, give me some hints to prove (1). Thanks.

PS: Now I think that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}}f(x)dx\right)^2-\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1f(x)^2dx=\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})\;\;(2)
$$
since the difference is 0 if $f$ is constant on each subinterval $(\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]$.

Please give me some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula is trying to prove

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2,$$ which is essentially wrong.

For instance, take the function $\text{sgn}(x-\frac12)$. For all $n$, the LHS integral is $0$ while the RHS sum is $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about proving (2)? I mean that is the big O order correct?

Comment: @Tony: I am not sure that your estimate works without any smoothness assumption, but so far I can't prove it.

Comment: If I take it that $f$ is constant on each subinterval, then the difference in (2) should be zero. Am I right?

Comment: @Tony: of course, otherwise the formula would be of no use. I wonder what you would get with a piecewise constant function with alternating signs and absolute values growing in smaller and smaller intervals, but in such a way to remain in $L^2$.